# Can I compute the limit using $\lim_{x \to 0}e^x -1 =x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

To compute 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{(1+x)^{1 \over x}-(1+2x)^{1 \over 2x} \over \sin x}$$

and we know that $e^{{1 \over x}\ln(1+x)} = {(1+x)^{1 \over x}}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}{{1 \over x}\ln(1+x)}=0$

Why can't I compute this as following:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{(e^{{1 \over x}\ln(1+x)}-1)-(e^{{1 \over 2x}\ln(1+2x)}-1) \over x}$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{{{1 \over x}\ln(1+x)-{1 \over 2x}\ln(1+2x)}\over x}$$

Comment: This depends utterly on what your definitions are.  If it were me, I would use the fact that $x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{e}^0 = 1$.  No need for anything fancy there, though I don't know what the $x$ is doing on the RHS of your identity in the title.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from the next-to-the last line to the last line.  I think you're thinking of $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$ but that's not the same as what you have written in your title, and I don't se how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: You can compute the limit using $e^x-1=O(x)$. Contrary, the limit in the title is just a number ($0$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to 0} e^x-1=x$ is meaningless.

If you mean $(\lim_{x\to 0} e^x-1)=x$, the left side is a number, while the right side is a variable (function), how are they equal?

If you mean $\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x-1=x)$, then what's the meaning of a limit of an equation?

I guess you mean $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$, but you cannot use this to replace $e^x-1$ with $x$ to calculate other limits, because there is no rule allowing you to do so.